# I sent I-751 to remove 2 year conditoinal but USCIS extended it for 1 year

Tags: usa, greencard

I have got a Green Card through my marriage and as we all know, that it is two step process

1. You receive conditional Green Card for 2 years.
2. File I -751 to remove the conditional status from it
3. You receive a Green Card for 10 years.

Well, I did file my I-751 and and they sent me a Notice of Action (I-797) which says that

**Your conditional resident status is extended for a period of one year**

Not sure why is that. Any ideas?

Comment: Your petition hasn't been approved yet. While it's being adjudicated, you've been given a [1 year extension](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/free-books/fiance-marriage-visa-book/chapter16-19.html).

Comment: @mkennedy that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I couldn't find a USCIS website quickly for an authoritative answer. Thus, the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. You will remain a conditional permanent resident for as long as the Removal of Conditions application is pending. The Removal of Conditions application could take anywhere from 6 months to a year, but could be longer.

Your green card will be expired soon, and you won't have a proof of permanent residency after that during the pendency of the Removal of Conditions application until it is approved and you receive the 10-year non-conditional green card. So they made the receipt of the I-751 application also serve as a 1-year extension of the green card to serve as a proof of permanent residency in the interim. If for some reason your application is still pending close to the end of that one year, you can continue to get further proof of permanent residency in the form of an I-551 stamp in your passport.